# Kids book in early 80s about a girl and her computer?

Tags: story-identification

This was a kids (or young adult book) back in the early 80s. It was about a girl who had a computer that she would talk to or type on, my memory is not clear on this. She was your typical troubled teen and had issues with her parents, but her computer was her "friend".

I remember one bit from the book the computer kept saying (displaying) something like "Beep Bop emoch" or something similar.

I know that's not much to go on but I was about 10 at the time and that was a long time ago. I don't think it was a great book, but I have always wondered what it was called and what it was really about.